# What does "=>address" mean in Ghidra's disassembly, at the end of an instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, ghidra

I am new to assembly & Ghidra and I am seeing a => on some lines for PUSH in a binary I am looking at and I cant seem to find what Ghidra is doing for instructions like this:

```
0040298b 56  PUSH   ESI=>DAT_004046c8
```

Comment: As we can see from the machine code ([single byte `56`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push)), it's a normal `push esi` instruction, pushing the register to the ESP stack.  I don't know what the `=>DAT_004046c8` annotation means; possibly that it's done some static analysis to figure out the necessary value of the register at that point?  Is there a previous instruction like `mov esi, OFFSET DAT_004046c8`?

Comment: (I retitled your question because it has no meaning in *assembly*, i.e. in source code that you'd feed to an assembler to get machine code.  Most assemblers would reject it as invalid characters at the end of a line.  It's still perhaps an interesting question about Ghidra's disassembly / analysis, although the later part of the question guessing about that instruction doing something else is something you might want to edit out.)

Comment: Ok thanks! You're right it was most likely an addition that Ghirda made after the automatic analysis was run and I was looking for a => operator in assembly and not in Ghidra documentation.  There is a previous instruction that is ```mov esi, OFFSET DAT_004046c8```

Comment: Ok, then yeah it's just tracking register values for you.  I'd guess it might use the same annotation for a `mov [esp], esi` instruction (if stack space for a function arg was already reserved, like `gcc -maccumulate-outgoing-args`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Ghidra annotating the assembly because it could statically infer that the value of ESI is `OFFSET DAT_004046c8` (from the previous instruction). This is a typical feature for Reverse Engineering tools, so you don't have to mentally keep track of all known values and the meaning of a certain offset yourself. This becomes especially if you rename the location `DAT_004046c8` to something more meaningful like `custom_variable_name`(once you found out what the "real" variable name could have been), the disassembly will show

```
0040298b 56  PUSH   ESI=>custom_variable_name
```